# Looking for link between Monitors listed in CurrentControlSet and ones returned by WmiMonitorID

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, registry

I am building a program to collect monitor information but have not been able to find a link between the items I found in the registry listed under "CurrentControlSet" and the items returned when querying "WmiMonitorID" from powershell. Does anyone know of any way to link the two items?

When looking online I did not find anyone that had made a connection between these two objects. I was unable to find any links myself when digging through Win32 classes and related Wmi objects. I was able to find some references to the items in Win32 classes but none that linked the 2 objects together. Not sure if it is doable but if anyone knows how or can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
This is what the data I am getting returned from both sources looks like. I was hoping the Instance Name(I named it Device Id in my object) would match up with the Device Id from the registry info.

[Monitor Registry Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq7IX.png)

[Monitor Wmi Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Vh9.png)

Comment: WmiMonitorID.InstanceName?

Comment: @Anders I was originally hoping that the Instance Name returned by Wmi would match up with the Device Id returned by the registry data but unfortunately that has not been the case for any of the machines I have tested on. I updated my post with screenshots of what the data my computer returns with a single monitor.

Comment: For me it matches with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY

Comment: @Anders That matches up for me too! Thank you so much for your help! I don't know how I had not seen to check there when looking for where monitor information is stored.